# Escape characters are not working when passing program arguments from shell script to jar

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

When I tried to pass some program arguments from shell script to java program, the escape characters are not working. 
Here is the code and command I tried to use. 
**Shell Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="DX.jar"
uid="111,110"

onCallName1="Tom"
onCallName2="Jerry"
onCallName3="Brun"

text="These are people who are on call: @$onCallName1, @$onCallName2 and @$onCallName3. \\n'
Please focus on the cases of online problems. \\n'
Safe cases monitor: https://a.b.com/page/992645614 \\n'
Old cases log: https://a.b.com/page/1012464399 \\n'
Cases feedback: https://a.b.com/page/1041338613"


# run!
java -jar $filename -uid $uid -text $text
```

The argument `text` should be parsed in the Java program and output itself like follows:

> These are people who are on call: @$onCallName1, @$onCallName2 and @$onCallName3.
> Please focus on the cases of online problems.
> Safe cases monitor: https://km.sankuai.com/page/992645614
> Old cases log: https://km.sankuai.com/page/1012464399
> Cases feedback: https://km.sankuai.com/page/1041338613

But when I run this shell script like `bash a.sh`, it only outputs these:

> These

Could anyone help me and give me some advice?
Thanks in advances.

Comment: The last line of the script probably should contain `"$text"` instead of just `$text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting your script as follow and please tell if it works or not for you too:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="DX.jar"
uid="111,110"

onCallName1="Tom"
onCallName2="Jerry"
onCallName3="Brun"

text="These are people who are on call: @$onCallName1, @$onCallName2 and @$onCallName3. \n'
Please focus on the cases of online problems. \n'
Safe cases monitor: https://a.b.com/page/992645614 \n'
Old cases log: https://a.b.com/page/1012464399 \n'
Cases feedback: https://a.b.com/page/1041338613"


# run!
java -jar "$filename" -uid "$uid" -text "$text"
```

In other words:

1. Leave carriage returns unescaped.
2. Put java command line arguments inside double quotes.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained what was changed, and why.

Comment: Sure, sorry. I edit my post.